# Store result in df using function with additional arguments

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function which returns a data frame consisting of columns provided by user as a parameter (to be precise - user provides columns indices which he wants to return). When I'm passing one additional argument (so it's one column) my function works fine but when I add another argument (e.g. extra 3 columns' indices) then it throws an error. Where is the problem?

My example is based on `quakes` dataset available in R:

```
myFunc <- function(data, ...){
  df <- data.frame()

  for (i in list(...)) {
      col <- data[i]      
      df <- rbind(df,col)
  }
  return(df)
}
```

for the function below it works fine:

```
myFunc(quakes, 3)
```

but here it throws an error:

```
myFunc(quakes, 1,2,3)
```

Error goes: *'match.names(clabs, names(xi))':
names do not match previous names
Called from: match.names(clabs, names(xi))*

I also tried with `cbind` but it also doesn't work.

Comment: What is the error message?  What is your input dataset?  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: My example is reproducible, I'm using `quakes` dataset which is available in R environment. I added error to my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cbind` only works if the dataframes have the same number of rows.
The initial dataframe you used has zero rows and you can't bind it to a non zero rows column.
Try :

```
myFunc <- function(data, ...){
  initdone <- F
  for (i in list(...)) {
    col <- data[i]
    if (!initdone) {
      df <- col
      initdone <- T
    } else {
      df <- cbind(df,col)
    }
  }
  return(df)
}


 myFunc(quakes, 1,2,3)
       lat   long depth
1   -20.42 181.62   562
2   -20.62 181.03   650
3   -26.00 184.10    42
4   -17.97 181.66   626
5   -20.42 181.96   649
```

Comment: Thanks! Just right before you get posted the answer I also got to the conclusion, that I must initialize df with some data and then use `cbind`, thanks for help!